# Relative path to resources in Yii

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii

I've developed site using Yii framework. All went well on local machine, but when i deployed it to client's server, i've ran into issue with resource files (css,js,images).

The url for site is something like this: `subdomain.domain.com/site` . When i access it, everything works, except that i have no css, js or images. In browser's console i noticed that page is trying to access resources at the wrong place, namely it is looking for `subdomain.domain.com/js` (or /css, or /images) instead of `subdomain.domain.com/site/js`.

Is there any way to change path used to look for resource files, so that i don't have to change every single link in the project? (I tried changing basePath in config, but it seems like it's not the path i should be changing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try adding some rules to do this, although you should really fix it in the code that generates the content.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(js|css|images)/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^ /site%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: I would assume that there is no way to force framework to look for resources in some other folder easily? Adding rules is not an option for me since there are many projects at the root, so this would not work too well (I do realize it's valid solution)